# check if setter was used

Tags: angular, angular-test, ts-mockito

I have a setter/getter in my service

```
export class fooService {
  set foo(value: number): void {
    this._privateFoo = value;
  }
  get foo(): number {
    return this._privateFoo;
  }
```

Now i mocked the service using ts-mockito and want to check if the setter has been called. I tried checking the variable via the getter on the instance but this does not return my value.

component (FooComponent):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.fooService.foo = 2;
  console.log('Foo Service is now:', this.fooService.foo);
```

unit test:

```
mockFooService = mock(FooService);
fooService = instance(mockFooService);
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 declarations: [ FooComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: FooService: useValue: fooService }
...

component.ngOnInit();
expect(fooService.foo).toEqual(2);
```

The Test prints `Foo Service is now: 2` but the `expect` fails with `Expected null to equal 2`.

Comment: do you have getter for `foo`?

Comment: Not sure about this, but maybe you just have the getter missing ?

Comment: without getter value of `foo` is null. the real value is in `_privateFoo` and there no way get real value.

Comment: I have a getter (just added it to the question). Otherwise the console log would not print anything out.

Comment: You are not showing the whole test structure in your post, how are you including the component in the test?

Comment: @Lucho i added this to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Problem was obvious: If i mock the service, it is not working anymore.
What i should do is either mock a setter and check if it is called or use the actual service.

Comment: Depends on how complex your service is in your testing, if it has alot of dependencies that actually has nothing to do what you wanna test I would go with mocking the service

Answer (score 0):

Use setter and getter together.

```
set foo(value: number): void {
  this._privateFoo = value;
}

get foo(): number{
  return this._privateFoo;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i do have a getter. I added it to my question.